# Match regex pattern for array of dollar denominations

Tags: c#, regex

A user can input the following:
*I $1 $5 $10 $20 $50 $100*

Ordering is not important, and I'm not worried if they enter a denomination more than once (i.e. I $1 $5 $5).  The beginning of the input starts with a capital "I" followed by a space.

What I have so far is this but I'm not too familiar with regex and cannot make it match my desired pattern:

> ^I\s(\$1|\$[5]|\$10|\$20|\$50|\$[100])$

I want to validate that the input is valid.

Comment: what do you want to receive? an array of numbers or validate that input?

Comment: regex is not a good tool for this problem.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov I want to see if the input is valid (updated question)

Comment: Instead of regex, try splitting the string on the `space`, and then use `Decimal.TryParse` and pass in the Currency format.

Comment: You can do this with regex, I don't see why you wouldn't.  I believe that my implementation is concise and correct.  Check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
regex = "^I(?:\s\$(?:10?0?|20|50?))+$"
```

`^I` says begins with `'I'`
`(?:\s\$` says group, but do not capture whitespace followed by a `'$'` followed by the next expression
`(?:10?0?|20|50?)` says group, but do not capture 1 followed by up to two 0's **or** 20 **or** 5 followed by up to one 0
`+` says at least one match
`$` says ends with the preceding

Comment: +1 for the explanation.  I love it when people explain their regex.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to expect after `I` either a space, or a `$1`, `$5`, etc...

```
string[] options = 
            {
                "I $1 $5 $10 $20 $50 $100",
                "I $1 $5 $5",
                "I wrong",
                "$1 $5 $5",
                "I",
                "I ",
            };
var reg = new Regex(@"^I\s(\s|(\$1|\$5|\$10|\$20|\$50|\$100))*$");

foreach (var option in options)
{
    var status = reg.Match(option).Success ? "valid" : "invalid";
    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> is {1} (length: {2})", option.PadRight(25), status, option.Length);
}
```

prints:

```
I $1 $5 $10 $20 $50 $100  -> is valid (length: 24)
I $1 $5 $5                -> is valid (length: 10)
I wrong                   -> is invalid (length: 7)
$1 $5 $5                  -> is invalid (length: 8)
I                         -> is invalid (length: 1)
I                         -> is valid (length: 2)
```

Comment: This is incorrect: `"I"` matches.  It is also unnecessarily long and captures instead of just grouping.

Comment: @SteveP. thanks for a good catch. `also unnecessarily long` agree, but  are you sure your options sufficiently short? Also, have you tried your pattern for `"I "`? Should it pass?

Comment: It should not pass, I assume.  I believe that mine correctly classifies what is needed, and is shorter.

Answer (score -1):

You use regex with check on digits

```
I[\s\$\d]*$
```

Howeever I would suggest u use String.Split(' ', input) and go from there

Comment: This does not work for myriad reasons.  It works for valid examples, but also accepts many invalid examples.